# Gitlab CI/CD Gradle Clean Build File not found

Tags: bash, docker, gradle, continuous-integration, gitlab

EDIT: To anyone who runs into this, I think the reason why this wasn't working is because

A) I didn't have the `WORKDIR /home/gradle/project` correctly set.

B) I'm not sure why, when I set `ENTRYPOINT ["gradle", "clean", "build", "--debug"]` at the end of the Dockerfile, which runs at the beginning of my stage in the Gitlab runner, I see the error. But when I remove the `ENTRYPOINT...` and just leave the WORKDIR at the end of the Dockerfile, `gradle clean build` can successfully run as a script option in the pipeline.

Does anyone know why that is?

---

I'm setting up a gitlab CI/CD pipeline using gradle to build java code.

I had gradle working with an old image, and made the mistake of overwritting the image tag in gitlab. I'm using the same docker build file that was working before that's now throwing an error saying a file can't be found.

This is my docker file

```
FROM gradle:4.6-jdk8

USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y --allow-unauthenticated install docker-ce

RUN apt-get -y install python-pip
RUN pip install awscli

USER gradle

ENTRYPOINT ["gradle", "clean", "build"]
```

This is the error being shown

```sh
14 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15 * What went wrong:
16 The specified settings file '/home/gradle/if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then
17  exec /usr/local/bin/bash 
18 elif [ -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then
19  exec /usr/bin/bash 
20 elif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then
21  exec /bin/bash 
22 elif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then
23  exec /usr/local/bin/sh 
24 elif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then
25  exec /usr/bin/sh 
26 elif [ -x /bin/sh ]; then
27  exec /bin/sh 
28 elif [ -x /busybox/sh ]; then
29  exec /busybox/sh 
30 else
31  echo shell not found
32  exit 1
33 fi
34 ' does not exist.
35 * Try:
36 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
37 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
38 BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

I'm building a "build image" locally and pushing it to Gitlabs docker repo with these commands
`docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/x/project:java-build -f ./docker/build.dockerfile .`
`docker push registry.gitlab.com/x/project`

file structure is
- .gradle
- docker
  - build.dockerfile
- src

and I'm calling the build commands from the root of the project

My understanding from this error message is that gradle is not being properly created resulting in no files showing up in the system.

I've run the pipeline with the --debug and --stacktrack option set on the gradle clean build and I didn't see any extra useful information.

I think I'm missing something fairly obvious but I'm not sure what it is...